# How to exclude existing table of db from alembic without stating a every single table in include_object(func) in env.py. Is there any automated way

Tags: migration, fastapi, alembic, alchemy

I have written every single table in `IGNORE_TABLES` to exclude the table from `alembic revision --autogenerate`, didn't found any automated solution, which auto detects the tables not included in `target_metadata = Base.metadata`, and exclude them from migration.

```py
IGNORE_TABLES = ["django_migrations", "django_content_type", "django_admin_log", "auth_group", "auth_group_permissions",
                 "django_session", "oms_role", "oms_user", "oms_entitymodel", "oms_user_group", "oms_user_roles",
                 "enterprise_company", "enterprise_branch", "enterprise_department", "enterprise_designation",
                 "enterprise_designationattachment", "oms_user_user_permissions", "oms_tenantconfiguration",
                 "oms_microservicesconfig", "oms_user_groups", "enterprise_section", "employee_employmentmodel",
                 "oms_tenantconfiguration_micro_services", "employee_employee_employment_model", "auth_permission"]


def include_object(object, name, type_, reflected, compare_to):
    if type_ == 'table' and name in IGNORE_TABLES:
        return False
    return True
```

Tried the `include_object` in `run_migrations_offline` and `run_migrations_online`, want to find the automated solution.